# A word to describe someone constantly seeking bewilderment

Tags: etymology, adjectives

So, Jason Silva coined the noun "wonderjunkie" to define this exact thing. However, I'm wondering if there's any adjective in ANY language to describe someone who is in constant search of awe, someone who constantly seeks to be in a state of bewilderment. Anyone????

Comment: You're looking for a single word, right? Adrenaline junkie would work well, otherwise.

Comment: Not in the sense that I tend to use it, though. It's someone who wants to be curious.

Comment: Ah, I just saw awe and not bewilderment.  A philosopher, maybe? "The term 'philosopher' comes from the Ancient Greek φιλόσοφος (*philosophos*) meaning 'lover of wisdom'." - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher)

Comment: It could work...I need an adjective though. Thank you :)!

Comment: I hadn't heard it before, but I love "wonderjunkie".  It conveys the intended nuanced meaning without any explanation.  By construction it should be a noun, but it could be used as an adjunct: "his wonderjunkie lifestyle".

Comment: Hello, Jessica. Requests for foreign words are strictly off-topic.

Comment: Do you really mean bewilderment?  "The condition of being confused or disoriented"  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bewilderment

Comment: It does have a certain geo-cachet, but I think it implies a neglect of other responsibilities.

Comment: How about 'a star-gazer' and 'star-gazing'? Star-gazer is the name of a tent model by Marmot, mostly mesh so that you can really sleep under the stars. What better than a starry sky can give you a sense of awe and bewidlerment, dizziness, even? And it is addictive… Not advertising anything, but that's how I first heard the phrase…

Answer (score 1):

*Inquisitive* may work.

> (of a ​person or a person’s ​behavior) ​eager to ​know a lot about
>   ​people or things

- [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/inquisitive)